# Using m4 to convert a string to ASCII codepoints

Tags: c, character-encoding, ascii, m4

This should be possible, but as I am a novice with m4, I'm not sure how to go about it, or how to write an algorithm to do so (in m4).

edit:

Just solved it, anyway for future reference, I have a series of characters, they need to be translated to their equivalent ASCII code points, e.g.

```
ascii(-{COLON}-, -{:}-) => #define TKN_COLON 58
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Also, could you please edit your question to include example input and output?

Comment: Still not ideal, but an improvement: `perl -e 'print ord "$2"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished this with the following code section

```
divert(-1)
changequote(-{,}-)
changecom(/*,*/)
define(-{ascii}-,-{#define TKN_-{}-$1 esyscmd(-{python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.write('%d'%ord('$2'))"}-)}-)
divert(0)dnl
```

I would greatly appreciate if anyone knows of a better way to do this (e.g. native m4, or more portable shell command).

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of others interested in a pure m4 implementation I've managed to create the following conversion macro. It has to meddle with the quoting characters to support normal m4 quote chars. It could be simplified a bit if that isn't important.

```
changequote(<!,!>) # Change quotes so we can handle "`" and "'"

# Change quotes every time this macro is called
define(<!asciiord!>,<!changequote(<!,!>)<!!>_asciiord(<!$1!>)<!!>changequote`'dnl
!>)

# Convert chars one at a time in the string argument
define(<!_asciiord!>,<!ifelse(<!$1!>,,, dnl
  <!_aconv(substr(<!$1!>,0,1))<!!>ifelse(len(<!$1!>),1,,<!,!>) $0(substr(<!$1!>,1))!>)!>)

# Map ASCII chars to their integer index by position
# Control chars are not supported.
# If the comment character is changed you must alter the map accordingly
define(<!_aconv!>,<!ifelse(<!$1!>,<! !>,32,<!$1!>,<!#!>,35,dnl
  <!index(<!                                 !" $%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ !>,<!$1!>)!>)!>)

changequote # Restore normal quoting chars
```

Usage:

```
asciiord(`hello') --> 104, 101, 108, 108, 111
```

Comment: For a variation, see autoconf's `m4sugar` macro `m4_cr_all` which uses `m4_format()` and two `for(1,255,...)` loops to create a format string of 255 "%c" and the sequence 1,2,3,...255. It modifies the set slightly for its own purposes (regex). I have adapted that and your code to generate templates for string-indexed SNMP data. (I disremember why I thought `m4` would be a good plan in the first place, but I'm stuck with it now...)